# i want sum this table rows using php

Tags: php

please can some one help me sum this using php

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">month</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>G</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="9">2011</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>November</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>December</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Year Total</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>0</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Year % of grand Total</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="9"><blockquote>
        <blockquote>
          <p>2012</p>
        </blockquote>
      </blockquote></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>November</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>December</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Year Total</th>
      <th>52</th>
      <th>27</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>0</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Year % of grand Total</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I wanted to sum the above table rows as i did for this sample diagram but i have fail. the query is looping and summing all rows . pls can some one help me solve this problem

```html
<?php 
 $db=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or
  die ("Unable to connect to the database,check parameter connection");
 mysql_select_db('dbname',$db) or die (mysql_error($db));
 $csv_output = '';
?>

<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tr>
<th scope="row">month</th>
<th>North West</th>
<th>North Central</th>
<th>North East</th>
<th>South South</th>
<th> South East</th>
<th>South West</th>
<th>Foreigners</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <?php
$startdate = 2011;
$enddate = date("Y");
$years = range ($startdate,$enddate);
foreach($years as $year)
{
  echo '<tr>
<th colspan="9">'.$year .'</th>
</tr>
';
$month = strtotime($year.'-01-01');
$end = strtotime($year.'-12-01');
while($month <= $end)
{
 ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo date('F', $month); ?></td>
   <td>
<?php  
 $num = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE PolZone = 'North West' AND Effective like '%".date('Y-m', $month)."%'"); echo $sun[] = mysql_num_rows($num);  $csv_output .= mysql_num_rows($num);?> </td>

<td>  <?php $num = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE PolZone = 'North Central' AND Effective like '%".date('Y-m', $month)."%'"); echo $sunb[] =mysql_num_rows($num); $csv_output .= mysql_num_rows($num). ", ";;?> 
</td>
<td>  <?php $num = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE PolZone = 'North East' AND Effective like '%".date('Y-m', $month)."%'"); echo $sunc[] = mysql_num_rows($num); $csv_output .= mysql_num_rows($num). ", ";;?> 
</td>
<td>  <?php $num = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE PolZone = 'South South' AND Effective like '%".date('Y-m', $month)."%'"); echo $sund[] =mysql_num_rows($num); $csv_output .= mysql_num_rows($num). ", ";;?> 
</td>
<td>  <?php $num = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE PolZone = 'South West' AND Effective like '%".date('Y-m', $month)."%'"); echo $sune[] =mysql_num_rows($num); $csv_output .= mysql_num_rows($num). ", ";;?> 
</td>
<td>  <?php $num = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE PolZone = 'South East' AND Effective like '%".date('Y-m', $month)."%'"); echo $sunf[] =mysql_num_rows($num); $csv_output .= mysql_num_rows($num). ", ";;?> 
</td>
<td>  <?php $num = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE PolZone = 'Foreigners' AND Effective like '%".date('Y-m', $month)."%'"); echo $sung[] =mysql_num_rows($num); $csv_output .= mysql_num_rows($num). "\n";;?> 
</td>
<?php   $month = strtotime("+1 month", $month); ?>
  </tr>
  <?php }  ?>
  <tr>
<td>  <?php  echo 'total';  ?>
<td>  <?php  
echo array_sum($sun);  ?>
<td><?php  
echo array_sum($sunb);  ?>
<td><?php  
echo array_sum($sunc);  ?>
<td><?php  
echo array_sum($sund);  ?>
<td><?php  
echo array_sum($sune);  ?>
<td><?php  
echo array_sum($sunf);  ?>
<td><?php  
echo array_sum($sung);  ?></td> 
  </tr>
<?php } ?>  


</table>
```

Comment: Please show your code,that you have tried so far

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: <?php $sum[] = mysql_num_rows($num);
echo array_sum($sum); ?> i have collect the values in array

Comment: Please also add the PHP code (including mysql_query etc.) to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format your result in a associate array and looping through for your expected table view.

Show you a very old school way...

```
<!--

    <?php
    $array = array(
        '2011' => array(
            'January' => array(0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1),
            'February' => array(3, 5, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0),
            'March' => array(0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2),
        ),
        '2012' => array(
            'January' => array(3, 5, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0),
            'February' => array(0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2),
            'March' => array(0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1),
        )
    );
    ?>

    <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">month</th>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>E</th>
                <th>F</th>
                <th>G</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
            foreach ($array as $year => $months) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="9"><?php echo $year; ?></th>
                </tr>

                <?php
                $sum1 = 0;
                $sum2 = 0;
                $sum3 = 0;
                $sum4 = 0;
                $sum5 = 0;
                $sum6 = 0;
                $sum7 = 0;
                foreach ($months as $month => $values) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $month; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $values[0]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $values[1]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $values[2]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $values[3]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $values[4]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $values[5]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $values[6]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $sum1 = $sum1 + $values[0];
                    $sum2 = $sum2 + $values[1];
                    $sum3 = $sum3 + $values[2];
                    $sum4 = $sum4 + $values[3];
                    $sum5 = $sum5 + $values[4];
                    $sum6 = $sum6 + $values[5];
                    $sum7 = $sum7 + $values[6];
                }
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th>Year Total</th>
                    <th><?php echo $sum1; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $sum2; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $sum3; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $sum4; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $sum5; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $sum6; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $sum7; ?></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Year % of grand Total</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: the game is beyond this one. pls check the second code snippet and see the full game. thank bro

Comment: as i said its better to fetch all the results in an associative array then process it for your view. that way code will be more organized and easy to debug